# convert varchar to array in presto sql

Tags: sql, arrays, string, hive, presto

I want to get jaccard similarity on varchar columns
There are two columns with varchar(string)

I want to change the column value like below
**from apple (varchar) to [a,p,p,l,e] (array)**

```
select 
  column
  ,split(column,',') as column_array 
  ,split(column, '') as column_array2 
from sample_table
```

but there is no delimiter, so the split function doesn't work.
Is there any function to change the string to array(or list) ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `regexp_extract_all` with `.` pattern (matches any character (except for line terminators)):

```
select regexp_extract_all('apple', '.');
```

Output:

```
      _col0      
-----------------
 [a, p, p, l, e]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a database that supports regular expressions, you could use the regexp_split_to_array function to split the string into an array of characters.

```
SELECT
  column,
  regexp_split_to_array(column, '') AS column_array
FROM
  sample_table;
```

If Regular Expression is not supported then you need to use a loop or a user-defined function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_to_array_of_chars(input_str VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR[] AS $$
DECLARE
  char_array VARCHAR[] := '{}';
  i INT;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(input_str) LOOP
    char_array := array_append(char_array, SUBSTRING(input_str FROM i FOR 1));
  END LOOP;
  RETURN char_array;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT
  column,
  string_to_array_of_chars(column) AS column_array
FROM
  sample_table;
```

You can achieve your goal of converting a VARCHAR column into an array of characters in Presto by using a workaround that doesn't require regular expressions or user-defined functions. Here's how you can do it using a numbers table

- Create a Numbers Table: If you don't have a numbers table, create one
  with a single column containing consecutive numbers.
- Split Characters: Use the numbers table to simulate splitting each
  character of the VARCHAR column into an array.

  CREATE TABLE numbers (num INT);
  INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (1), (2), (3), ...;

  ```
   -- Split Characters
   SELECT
     st.column,
     ARRAY_AGG(SUBSTRING(st.column FROM n.num FOR 1)) AS column_array
   FROM
     sample_table st
   CROSS JOIN
     numbers n
   WHERE
     n.num <= LENGTH(st.column)
   GROUP BY
     st.column;
  ```

Comment: seems presto doesn't support the regexp_split_to_array :(

Comment: and also, I am using zepplin as the interpreter and seem it doesn't support the udf as well. :(

Comment: You can achieve your goal of converting a VARCHAR column into an array of characters in Presto by using a workaround that doesn't require regular expressions or user-defined functions. Here's how you can do it using a numbers table refer the edited code

Answer (score 0):

Oh I tried to regexp_replace funtion like below and it works!

```
array_remove(array_remove(split(regexp_replace(column,'', ','),','), ' '),'')
```